# SUM two columns of two different tables in one result based group by id of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, left-join

I have 3 tables:

Users:

```
id                 | account_name
-------------------|----------------------|
18                 | panic                |
```

Deposits:

```
id                 | user_id     | amount
-------------------|---------------------------|
1                  | 18          | 100          
2                  | 18          | 100
```

Withdrawals:

```
id                      | user_id          | amount
------------------------|--------------------------------|
1                       | 18          | 200          
2                       | 18          | 200
```

and i'm trying to get a result like:

```
id                      | totalDeposits  | totalWithdraws
------------------------|---------------------------|
18                      | 200            | 400
```

Now when i try to get the totals for some reason they are cross adding themselves up, of course if there are no rows it should return 0.

```
SELECT t0.id,IFNULL(SUM(t1.amount),0) AS totalWithdrawals,
IFNULL(SUM(t2.amount),0) AS totalDeposits
FROM users t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN withdrawals t1 ON (t0.id = t1.user_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN deposits t2 ON (t0.id = t2.user_id) 
GROUP BY t0.id
```

Any idea how to do this cross join or where am i summing them wrong?

Comment: The desired result doesn't make a lot of sense. What is user_id `18` is doing in the same column as deposits total? And how come `id` column mixes again a user_id `18` and a deposit/withdrawal id `2`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @peterm Edited the desired result, had a wrong row, user_id is the relation between Deposits-Accounts and Withdrawals-Accounts

Comment: Don't have separate tables for deposits and withdrawals. Just have a transactions table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT A.id,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Deposits WHERE user_id = A.id) totalDeposits, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Withdrawals WHERE user_id = A.id) totalWithdraws 
FROM users A
WHERE A.id = 18 -- WHERE can be removed to get all users details
```

Comment: You might want the COALESCE((select ....), 0) around the whole thing for the two fields if you don't want to have to worry about NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of

```
SELECT u.id, 
       COALESCE(d.amount, 0) totalDeposits,
       COALESCE(w.amount, 0) totalWithdrawals
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) amount 
      FROM deposits 
     GROUP BY user_id
  ) d ON u.id = d.user_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) amount 
      FROM withdrawals 
     GROUP BY user_id
  ) w ON u.id = w.user_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904947/5)

Result:

```
| id | totalDeposits | totalWithdrawals |
|----|---------------|------------------|
| 18 |           200 |              400 |
```

Comment: Multiple SUM() operations and GROUP BY operations will make this a very inefficient query, even if it gives the correct results.

Comment: @MichaelPost Did you run `explain` on it?

Comment: No, but the other solution above has a cleaner syntax that should produce a simpler query plan assuming that the tables are properly indexed on user_id.  You are doing a LEFT JOIN with a select from the whole table and a GROUP BY only to filter to the single value at the end.  I understand that the query parser may simplify the expression down behind-the-scenes, but the cleaner syntax of the earlier answer I think makes it a better one.  I prefer not to rely on the query parser to be too smart, although in this case perhaps it is.

Comment: Cleaner is very subjective but most importantly the other solution will execute two subqueries for each row in a users table (N*2) where as as proposed solution always does at most 3+1.

Comment: The other approach would a conditional aggregation as Strawberry suggested.

Comment: I would have thought the "where A.id = 18" on the outer SQL meant that each subquery is running once with a likely indexed column.  I'll need to think about what you said...

Comment: Where do you see such a constraint in OP's question? The query can be run against all users unless it's explicitly stated otherwise. What you refer to is a total speculation by the author of the other answer.

Comment: You brought up an interesting point.  I have changed my rating.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are generating a Cartesian product.  One solution is to aggregate first.  Another method is to use `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY`.  I would structure this as:

```
SELECT u.id,
       SUM(deposit) as deposits,
       SUM(withdrawal) as withdrawal
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     ((SELECT d.user_id, d.amount as deposit, 0 as withdrawal
       FROM deposits d
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT w.user_id, 0, w.amount 
       FROM withdrawals w
      )
     ) dw
     ON u.id = dw.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is, admittedly, a marked development from my own answer, but still, following on 6 hours later, I might have been tempted to suggest it as an edit rather than an answer in it's own right.